# iterating input() in generator

Tags: python, input, generator

Now I am working on a python course, but the data in the tasks there is formed as inputs, and not as arguments to the function, as for example in codewars.

To write generators, I have to use input, which cannot be iterated. It turns out this code:

```
dots = [input() for x in range(int(input()))]
parsedDots = [dot for dot in dots if not '0' in dot]
```

(This code should make a list where only inputs() without zero coordinate are taken into)

Is it possible, to combine this two generators into one?

Input data example:

```
4
0 -1
1 2
0 9
-9 -5
```

Comment: Why do you want to make one-liners? You're losing readability with that. Also, those are not generators, those are list comprehensions. Generators (basically iterator comprehensions - with () instead of []) can be used to evaluate stuff lazily but I don't think it's needed here

Comment: Neither are generators, they're list comprehensions that are trying to be overly clever

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @h4z3 as far as I know, in solving exercises one-liners are preferred.
I most likely will not use such constructions in real projects.
And sorry for the fact that I called it generators ;)

Comment: No, one-liners are not preferred. People like to do code golfing, but ultimately you're supposed to make something less complex - as in time complexity and memory complexity. Comprehensions are basically special syntax loops, they don't help with complexity - I'd say they worsen beginner code as you don't see your nesting easily and see that something's wrong. (Current python developer here, who loves comprehensions, but was in competitive programming since middle school)

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your check will also throw out inputs that include e.g. `"10"`

Comment: Turning to common sense, and PEP 20, you @h4z3 are most likely right, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @tobias_k Fixed it, the code in the topic was just a sketch, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them using [the walrus operator, `:=`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) in 3.8+:

```
parsedDots = [inp for _ in range(int(input())) if '0' not in (inp := input())]
```

Pre-3.8, the best you can do is convert your original list comprehension (eager, materializes a `list`) to a generator expression (lazy), so you don't make an actual `list` until after you've filtered out the garbage:

```
dots = (input() for _ in range(int(input())))  # Parens instead of square brackets makes genexpr
parsedDots = [dot for dot in dots if '0' not in dot]
```

That has *slightly* higher overhead than the walrus solution, but no meaningful per-item increase in peak memory usage, and it works on every version of Python since generator expressions were introduced (2.4ish?).